# R - Test whether a Data.Frame Cell is NULL/empty

Tags: sql-server, r, boolean-expression

I am passing data from SQL Server 2016 through the external script stored procedure to R for processing.

I want to either do e, or not do e depending on whether a cell at position [I,11] in a Data Frame has a integer value.

```
for(i in 1:2){
    if(d1[i,11]==""){
        d2[i,1]<-d1[i,1]
        d2$Ledger<-d1[i,2]
        d2$Account<-d1[i,3]
        d2$Title<-d1[i,4]
        d2$ActualTitle<-d1[i,5]
        d2$AccountNumber<-d1[i,6]
        d2$Sortcode<-d1[i,7]
        d2$PostCode1<-d1[i,8]
        d2$PostCode2<-d1[i,9]
        d2$AddressName<-d1[i,10]
        d2$MatchedID<-d1[i,11]
    }
```

I am struggling to find a way of doing this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further testing revealed that the value stored was NA in R, and using the function is.na(expression) yielded a Boolean return.

```
for(i in 1:2){
    if(is.na(d1[i,11])){
        d2[i,1]<-d1[i,1]
        d2$Ledger<-d1[i,2]
```

Answer (score -1):

The best approach would not be to use a loop. Vector operations are better when the size of data frame is huge.

For checking whether something is `<NA>`, use:

```
if(is.na(item))
```

This will return a `TRUE` if item is `<NA>`, else `FALSE`. Any missing value from SQL will be represented as `<NA>` in R. Similarly you can use `is.integer(item)` for checking if something is integer.

Then you can use the following for selective operation on the columns of a data frame:

```
dataframe$columnname[which(is.na(dataframe$column))] <- new_value
```

You can also use `ifelse` to do the same thing like:

```
> dataframe$columnname <- ifelse(is.na(dataframe$column), value_for_if_satisfied, value_for_else_satisfied)
```